# Fetch API calls itself more than once every time I try to register user except the first time

Tags: javascript, post, fetch-api

I am making SPA app with Vanilla JS - Client routing etc. Hosted on ASP Net Core.

I have problem with the register method, I am using JS fetch API to post to my Identity API which is ASP net Core API - using Microsoft Identity. I think that I have enabled Cors on the Identity API and it seams to work.

When I post to the Identity API Registration Data to register user the first time all is fine.

But when I try to register another user the fetch API POST is called twice. It seams that it Post the new user and than it tries to register the previous user that I already have registered.

Because it tries to register the previous user again I get error from the api that the user already exists which is normal.

I am not sure if its CORS problem or something in the JS code. I am not sure if I use the fetch API correct as well. I have searched on the internet but cant get this to work.

If I register user the first time it works and if I try to register user again the fetch API is called twice, but if I refresh the SPA Page before I try to create the second user all is fine.

Now the interesting part is if I create 3 users without refresh and try to create the 4th the fetch API post the 4th user and its registered successful but than it tries to register all previous users again. So the fetch API is called 3 times after the registration of the 4th user.

**JS - REGISTER USER: Fetch API POST:**

```
function registerAccount() {

    const registerForm = document.getElementById('registerForm'); // Get the Form


    registerForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent page reload on Submit  

        LoadingMsg(); // Show Loading Message

        const formData = new FormData(this); // "this" = this Form
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(formData); // Get the form data params  
        let formQueryString = searchParams.toString(); // Get the form data params as string

        // https://simonplend.com/how-to-use-fetch-to-post-form-data-as-json-to-your-api/

        // POST
        fetch(identityApiUri + '/Account/Register?' + formQueryString,
            {    
                method: 'POST' 
                
            }).then(function (response)
               {
                alert("Before OK!!");
                 // IF OK                       
                   if (response.status == 201) // Status 201 = "Created"
                   {
                     RemoveLoadingMsg();
                     SuccessMsg("Success");
                       this.registerForm.reset(); // Reset the Form
                       alert("OK!!");
                       return;
                   }
                   else // If Bad STATUS
                   {
                       console.log("Register Error - Could not register");
                       return Promise.reject(response);  // Triggers Catch method
                   }
               
               }).catch(function (err) // CATCH
                  {
                  RemoveLoadingMsg();
                  // Handle error here
                  alert("Exception!!!!!!!!!!" + err);
                  console.warn('Post Exception:', err);
                  });
               
    });

}
```

**ASP NET CORE Identity API Startup.cs:**

```
using Leanheat.Identity.API.DBContexts;
using Leanheat.Identity.API.Filters;
using Leanheat.Identity.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Leanheat.Identity.API
{

    public class Startup
    {
        // Startup
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }






        // Configure Services ================================================================================= 
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        {
          


            // Log in - DbContext
            services.AddDbContextPool<LeanheatIdentityApiContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityContextConnection")));


            // UnitOfWork - Filter
            services.AddScoped<UnitOfWorkFilter>(); 
            services.AddControllers(config => { config.Filters.AddService<UnitOfWorkFilter>(); });  // UnitOfWork for all Controllers


            // CORS - Allow calling the API from WebBrowsers
            services.AddCors();

            // Log In
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<LeanheatIdentityApiContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders(); // AddDefaultTokenProviders is used for the Update Log In Password etc.







            // Log In
            // Make all Controllers protected by default so only Authorized Users can accsess them, for Anonymouse Users use [AlloAnonymouse] over the controllers.
            services.AddMvc(options => {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                  .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                  .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

            }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

            //services.AddControllers();



           


            // Swagger
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Leanheat.Identity.API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }









        // Configure ===========================================================================================
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        {
            // Default Code------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                // Swagger
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Leanheat.Identity.API v1"));
            }


         

            app.UseHsts(); // Allow HTTPS
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();


            // CORS - Allow calling the API from WebBrowsers
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true));// allow any origin  
                



            // Log In
            app.UseAuthentication(); // UseAuthentication SHOULD ALWAYS BE BEFORE Authorization
            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**THE SPA CLIENT ROUTING:**

```
// Imports
import Dashboard from "./views/Dashboard.js";
import Posts from "./views/Posts.js";
import Settings from "./views/Settings.js";
import Register from "./views/Register.js";


// Navigator--------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
const navigateTo = url => {
  history.pushState(null, null, url); // Add the url to the history APi of Js
  router();
};

                       

// Router------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
const router = async () => {
 const routes = [
   {path: "/", view: Dashboard}, // On Path "/" use the dashboard class and inject html in the #app div
   {path: "/posts", view: Posts },
   {path: "/settings", view: Settings },
   {path: "/Register", view: Register }
 ];

 

 

 // Test each route for potential match ----------------------------------------------------->
 // Get the current Url and check if its defined in routes method "Check if its one of our Spa Urls" ----------------------------------------------------->
 const potentialMatches = routes.map(route => {
  return {
      route: route,
      isMatch: location.pathname === route.path  // true if match else false
  };
 });




// Check if there is Match------------------------------------------------------------------->
    let match = potentialMatches.find(potentialMatch => potentialMatch.isMatch);  // Get isMatch from potentialMatches


 // If no match return to StartPage
 if(!match)
 {
     match = {
     route: routes[0],
     isMatch: true
     };
 }

 const view = new match.route.view(); // If match  use the routes array of the router and get the view function for the route

 document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = await view.getHtml();  // Get the #app div and use the view function to inject Html in it from the view class ex."Dashboard, Posts, Settings etc."
 
};





// On-Navigating-Back&Forth-Load the Content--Together with the url------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
window.addEventListener("popstate", router); // On popstate "If back button is pressed" use the router array to load back the previeous SPA View


// Listen to document fully Loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.body.addEventListener("click", e => { //Listen for click in the body
    if(e.target.matches("[data-link]")){  // If body item was clicked and its data-link decorated
      e.preventDefault();  // Prevent deafult behavior dont follow the link
      navigateTo(e.target.href);  // Navigate method   
    }
  });


router(); // Load the content if the url is defined in our "Spa Urls"
});

//#### Client Routing END #####
```

**SPA - Register VIEW:**

```
<form id="registerForm">
       <div name="register" class="inputContainer">

                <h4 class="title">Register</h4>
                <hr class="hrTitle">

        <diV class="colom">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input name="email" type="text" maxlength="25" id="email" class="form-control inputDark" />
            <label id="emailValidation"></label>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input name="password" type="text" maxlength="40" id="password" class="form-control inputDark" />
            <label id="passwordValidation"></label>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="repeatPassword">Repeat Password:</label>
            <input type="text" maxlength="40" id="repeatPassword" class="form-control inputDark" />
            <label id="repeatPasswordValidation"></label>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">FirstName:</label>
            <input name="firstname" type="text" maxlength="20" id="firstname" class="form-control inputDark" />
            <label id="firstNameValidation"></label>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname">LastName:</label>
            <input name="lastname" type="text" maxlength="20" id="lastname" class="form-control inputDark" />
            <label id="lastNameValidation"></label>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age">Age:</label>
            <input name="age" type="text" maxlength="3" id="age" class="form-control inputDark" />
            <label is="ageValidation"></label>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phonenumber">Phonenumber:</label>
            <input name="phonenumber" type="text" maxlength="8" id="phonenumber" class="form-control inputDark" />
            <label id="phonenumberValidation"></label>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rememberMe" class="subTitle" >Remember Me:</label>
            <input name="rememberMe" value="true" type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" class="form-control inputDark" />
        </div>
             </div>

        <button type="submit" onkeypress="javascript:registerAccount()" onmousedown="javascript:registerAccount(); " class="blue-dark-button">Enter</button>    
           </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: Possibility you redirecting?

Comment: How/where/when is `registerAccount()` called?

Comment: Have updated the question - its the SPA - Register VIEW: Its called from a button which is submitting the form and is also adding event listener for form submit.

Comment: OK, well that's your problem. Every call to `addEventListener()` does exactly what the method name implies: it **adds** an event listener, without removing any event listeners that have been added previously.

Comment: Ok, I just tried this but it does not work   this.removeEventListener("submit", this, true);

The event listener looks like this  

registerForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) { }

Comment: Just register the listener **once**.

Comment: Tha another  problem is that when I load the SPA View the JS scripts under the inserted html dont gets executed so its little hard to add event listener only when the view is loaded. Now I am adding the listener onmouse down before the submit. 

I gave the function a name and did this this.removeEventListener('submit', handler);  at the end and it works now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Pointy - I added event listener every time without removing the previous. This is why it posted every previous registration with the new registration.

I gave the submit event listeners function a name and at the end of the function I removed the event listener  this.removeEventListener('submit', handler);